# Parse.com GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, parsing, group-by, parse-platform

I am trying to do a count of likes on a parse table/class and wondering if there is anyway to do this in Parse?

```
Parse.com GROUP BY
```

Does Parse still not support it?

Comment: No there's no GROUP BY in Parse.com yet. Perhaps if you told us a little more about what you are trying to do, we could help you find a solution :-)

Comment: I'll change my model to adjust for this. thanks

Comment: Actually trying to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25839113/are-join-queries-slow-in-parse